# Single-threaded apartment COM components in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to use single-threaded apartment (STA) COM components in asp.net mvc framework?
WebForms support this by letting us set aspcompat attribute value to true.

How to do this in asp.net mvc?

Comment: I posted a detailed answer that works for asp.net mvc 3.0 [here](http://blogs.srivainc.com/index.php/2011/11/21/running-asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-on-sta-threads/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently AspCompat=true does not work under MVC.. Check this link for a work around
http://forums.asp.net/t/1302406.aspx/1